# How to keep relative hyperlinks working when exporting a PDF made with VBA to an Ipad

Tags: ios, excel, vba, pdf, hyperlink

I am currently developing on my Windows computer an Excel document with VBA which will generate a PDF file with relative hyperlinks (which looks like "References\text.txt") and I want to export the PDF file and the documents (like References\text.txt) on an Ipad.

In order to do this, I generate an hyperlink thanks to :
Hyperlinks.Add Cells(...), Address:="References\text.txt", TextToDisplay := ...

Then I use
.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=...
so as to export it as a PDF.

Finally, I upload it on an Ipad but it says that it can't find the document even though I exported both PDF and "References\text.txt".

When I click on the hyperlink in my Excel document or in the PDF on my computer, the preview show that the hyperlink points towards : file:///\\server\blabla...\References\text.txt (absolute path towards the "References\text.txt"), that is to say that it completed automatically the relative path with the path to where the excel document is.
The problem may come from here.

Furthermore, I read that Ipads use / in path rather than \ . Yet, when I modify Hyperlinks.Add address with "References/text.txt", it automatically converts the / to an \ and uses the absolute path again.

The hyperlinks work well on my computer, in both Excel and the generated PDF.

I found some interesting topics about this on StackOverflow, but they don't match nor work for me.

Therefore, is there a way to force Hyperlinks.Add to use relative path that work for Ipad ?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However it doesn't really match my question. I have all rights of access, the problem is that relative path are transformed as absolute path. The solution you are suggesting doesn't work, the path is transformed to the absolute path and the / are transformed to \.